# Python-Selenium3: open browser on Firefox 45

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I developed an automatic test tool with python 2.7 and using selenium 3.0.1.It works fine on Firefox 49. I need that it works also with Firefox 45. I tried it but the tool finds problem to open the browser. The piece of script is like the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

downloadPath="path/downloads"
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', downloadPath)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', 'application/x-targz, application/x-gzip, application/force-download')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/x-targz, application/x-gzip, application/force-download')
browser =  webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

This small program is fine working on Firefox 49, but in Firefox 45 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    browser =  webdriver.Firefox(profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.0.1-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.0.1-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I made searches in the internet and I found that I have to install geckodriver. 
I downloaded geckodriver from github: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases I extracted the tar.gz file and I added its path to PATH environment variable like that:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/Downloads/geckodriver
```

But I got the same error.
Does someone has an idea how I can fix this bug?

Comment: Firefox 45 is not supported in selenium 3.0.1. Support for Firefox is via Mozilla’s geckodriver.

Comment: does copying geckodriver executable to /usr/bin/ fixes the problem?

Comment: @NimaGhotbi I copied geckodriver to /usr/bin and now it works fine.
Thank you !!